# Squid cross compile

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, squid

I've been trying to cross compile the Squid 3.5.7 on **ARM Cortex A8** (Linux). 
I downloaded it from http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/ 
I have arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and arm-linux-gnueabi-g++.

```
tar -zxvf squid-3.5.7.tar.gz
cd squid-3.5.7
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid
make all
make install
```

Next I copy folders /usr/local/squid and ~/squid-3.5.7 to SD card. 
When I try open ./squid -z from SD card on the board with ARM I have problem:

```
root@am335x:/# ls
bin       etc       lib       mnt       srv       usr
boot      findHelp  linuxrc   proc      sys       var
dev       home      media     sbin      tmp
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin# ls
squid
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin# ./squid -z
./squid: line 20: syntax error: ")" unexpected
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin# ./squid
./squid: line 20: syntax error: ")" unexpected
root@am335x:/media/mmcblk0/squid/sbin#
```

I don't know what to do :/

Comment: I think you should tell to configure that it has to use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc otherwise it is going to use default gcc.

Comment: @Marco how to do it?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you compiling on the arm cortex A8 board or on a standard PC ?

Comment: where can I see it?
And how can I change it?

Comment: I think I did not explain very well: you said you are running configure .. make .. where are you running configure and make on your PC or on the arm cortex board ?

Comment: try this: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid --host=arm-linux

Comment: When I wanted to run it on the arm board I saw:
check 4 a BSD-compatible install... cfgaux/install-sh -c
check 4 a thread-safe mkdir -p... cfgaux/install-sh -c -d
check 4 gawk... no
check 4 mawk... no
check 4 nawk... no
check 4 awk... awk
check whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
check whether make supports nested variables... no
check whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
check 4 gcc... no
check 4 cc... no
check 4 cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/media/mmcblk0/squid-3.5.7':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' 4 more details

Comment: On the PC should be OK, just try with this ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid --host=arm-linux

Comment: after  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid --host=arm-linux in Makefile:
....
CC = gcc
CCDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CFLAGS = -Wall 
CGIEXT = .cgi
CHMOD = /bin/chmod
CPP = gcc -E 
...

Comment: my Makefile: http://wklej.se/makefile what must I change?

Comment: Normally you do not edit Makefiles you just delete it and rerun configure

Comment: after ./configure ... I have this makefiles

Comment: I will download squid and try on my pc tomorrow.

Comment: did you do it? @Marco

Comment: Yes and I have bad news it seems squid does not really like cross compiling, so I think it's going to be easier compiling it on your destination board. But you have to install gcc and binutils on your board first

Comment: how to install gcc and binutils if i don't have apt-get, make, .tar and other programs ?

Comment: I do not know your board but try this: http://releases.linaro.org/latest/components/toolchain/binaries/4.8/arm-eabi/

Comment: I can't install compiler :/

Comment: I am sorry I have run out of ideas

Comment: maybe I should use other version the Squid ?

Comment: I do not think it will work, you have already the latest stable release. Can you please tell me which board are you using ?

Comment: http://qiyangtech.en.alibaba.com/product/1820345578-219446304/Custom_IAC_335X_Kit_Cortex_A8_Dual_Ethernet_Board.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary which you have built is built for your PC architecture. To build squid for arm follow the below instructions.

The configure is trying to run a test which will fail if you are using a cross compiler so add a cache file to override those tests.

For example create a cache file squid.cache with the line shown below

```
squid_cv_gnu_atomics=no
```

Export the BUILDCXX variable required for compiling squid

```
export BUILDCXX=g++
```

Make sure you have exported the toolchain path to the path variable($PATH)

```
export PATH=<TOOLCHAIN_PATH>:$PATH
```

Then configure the squid by running the configure as shown below

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --cache-file=squid.cache --prefix=<install/dir>
```

Finally compile the squid by running make

```
make
```

Then install the binaries using make install

```
make install
```

Comment: could you talk me how to do it, please?

Comment: I have mentioned all the steps above. In which step do you have the doubt

Comment: first goto the squid source directory then create a file **squid.cache**  using any editor you prefer eg vim

Comment: Then add the line **squid_cv_gnu_atomics=no** to that file (squid.cache)

Comment: export the variable BUILDCXX by using the command **export BUILDCXX=g++**

Comment: what is the path of your  *arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc* binary

Comment: after I wrote  export BUILDCXX=g++  in command line I didn't see the path of my arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc binary. I saw nothing :/

Comment: Tell me the output of the this two commands **echo $PATH** and **which arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc**

Comment: jakub@Kuba:/$ export BUILDCXX=g++                              
jakub@Kuba:/$ echo $PATH      
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/bin

Comment: is **arm-arago-linux-gnueabi** the toolchain you need to use? if yes then send me the output of **ls /opt/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/bin**

Comment: jakub@Kuba:/$ which arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc               
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Comment: so you have built the other binaries for your board with arm-arago toolchain

Comment: i also have arm-arago-linux-gnueabi

Comment: You are not able to get me.What I am trying to say is you have to use the toolchain which you have previously used to build the binaries for the board so which is it arm-linux-gnueabi or arm-arago-linux-gnueabi

Comment: so arm-arago-linux-gnueabi

Comment: Then run the below command for configure **./configure --host=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi --cache-file=squid.cache --prefix=/usr/local/squid**

Comment: copy the binaries from the prefix _/usr/local/squid_ to your SD card.

Comment: while copying: "An error occurred while copying the file to the / media / jakub / 0E31-CE73 / squid / share / errors"

Comment: The file system does not support symbolic links

Comment: Are you not using ext 3/4 partition in your SD card

Comment: and after the installation i see: root@Kuba:/usr/local/squid# ls
etc  libexec  share

Comment: **file /dev/sdx**  where x is the partition of your SD card which you can find with **lsblk** command

Comment: root@Kuba:/media/jakub/0E31-CE73# file /dev/mmcblk0
/dev/mmcblk0: block special

Comment: can you run the below command **fdisk /dev/mmcblk0** and in that enter option **p** and give me the output

Comment: which is your root partition mmcblk0p2 or p4 and what is that written under system of your output

Comment: mmcblk0p1 -> system: unknown; p2 -> system: unknown; p4 -> system: lack

Comment: where are the other binaries present that is your bin, lib directory etc in your SD card

Comment: can i delete all partitions ?? and next create a new ?

Comment: can you list all the files present in your SD card using **tree** command